# CSS: is there any way to style an <ol> bullet so that it is circular and has a background?

Tags: html, css

DEMO that shows what I'm stuck with and what I want, which i can only do by manually adding in  tags:

http://jsfiddle.net/8nFEk/

Screenshot example:

[image: a busy cat]

```
<ol class="arabic">
<li>Step One</li>
</ol>

ol.arabic {
list-style: decimal;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, reset the default styling and use the various `counter` style [modifications](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Counters):

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/8nFEk/1/)**

```
ol.arabic {
    list-style-type: none;
    counter-reset: ol-counter;
}
ol.arabic > li:before {
    content: counter(ol-counter);
    counter-increment: ol-counter;
    color: white;
    background: #452073;
    border-radius: 140px;
    font-weight: 700;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 28px;
    text-indent: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right:4px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks much! I'd never seen the counter-reset in CSS before, and ended up also finding http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/counter-increment/ which was really helpful. :)